# How can I create a row where One Side is Higher than the other

Tags: html, css

[image: Row with different height on one end]

Hi guys how can I get a row to be higher on one side as seen below?

Thank you I'm really at a loss on how this can be done.

Comment: as seen where? To you got any example of what you want?

Comment: This was a design made in Sketch by a coworker, I'm trying to recreate it, haven't seen it live anywhere or have any examples unfortunately.

Comment: Can't you just use an image?

Comment: Yeah at Lurker I think thats what we may end up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `skewY()`

```css
div {
  /* margins for demnstration, not needed*/
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If it has content

```css
.wrapper {
  /* margins for demnstration, not needed*/
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
  background: orange;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.wrapper>.main {
  transform: skewY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll still have to take a bit of care of the content, because the wrapper isn't a straight line anymore.

Comment: Hi thanks that would work but then it would skew all of the contents of the div.  I'll try placing it in a div above it though.

Comment: you can apply the same value but negative on the children

Comment: Awesome great Idea I'll try that now!

Comment: not negative but the opposite if `10` then `-10` if `-10` then `10`

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a `<div>` element and css.

css:

```
div{
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px; 
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

You only have to use the `transform: rotate` property to rotate a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the top part to be like that you can consider pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  margin:50px;
  padding:10px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:10px;
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform:skewY(-5deg);
  background:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas finibus auctor porta. Aliquam at est sed ex venenatis luctus sit amet nec nisl. Maecenas consectetur sapien nulla,
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas finibus auctor porta. Aliquam at est sed ex venenatis luctus sit amet nec nisl. Maecenas consectetur sapien nulla,
</div>
```